# Hide deleted teams as options for developer title

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, developer-story

I've created a Team and *deleted* it. So, it shouldn't appear as an option when I'm selecting my title.

[image: drop-down]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment.